# Fade in effect for ng-repeat, for inserting elements at the top of a list

Tags: angularjs

I've seen examples on how to fade in when adding elements to the bottom, but not to the top.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the code example for inserting elements to the bottom with fade in animation?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2QuyxMt4kiYkKeCoMGCL?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please find the code for app.js (from your sample link in you comment) below:

```
angular.module("userApp", ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.usrList = [];
    $scope.adduser = function() {
        console.log($scope.newUsr)

        var item = {name: $scope.newUsr};
        $scope.usrList.splice(0, 0, item);
    }

});
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you very much!

Comment: var c = $scope.usrList.length + 1; is not used

Comment: @LastTribunal Thank you for your reminder. The unused code has been removed.

Comment: Actually, my problem was not having a named value in my array.

you can also replace 
var item = {name: $scope.newUsr};
 $scope.usrList.splice(0, 0, item);
with
 $scope.usrList.unshift(newUsr);